# odoo 14 get selected recored is tree view JS

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, rpc

I want to get the ids of the selected recored from a tree view

What is did is add a button to the view which when clicked I get the `self.selectedRecords` in my python function `test_func` but I am not getting the

**But I am getting `['sale.order_33', 'sale.order_40', 'sale.order_48']`**

instead of `['sale.order_19', 'sale.order_18', 'sale.order_2']`

[image]

```js
ListController.include({
        renderButtons: function($node) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            var self = this;
            if (this.$buttons) {
                $(this.$buttons).find('.oe_new_custom_button').on('click', function() {
                    rpc.query({
                        model: 'sale.order',
                        method: 'test_func',
                        args: [self.selectedRecords],
                    }).then(function(res){
                        console.log(self.selectedRecords);
                        console.log(res);
                    });
                });
            }
        },
    });
```

```py
class test_func_report(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
        
    @api.model
    def test_func(self,selectedRecords):
        _logger.warning(self)
        _logger.warning(selectedRecords)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [getSelectedIds()](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_controller.js#L97) method to get the currently selected records ids.

Use `self.getSelectedIds()` instead of `self.selectedRecords`.

Comment: what I want to do is create excel file `| consumer[key] | Country | product | Inventory Units | Sales Units |`  is the a was to get the sales record for a product thank you for the help if it large I can create a new question

Comment: I did not understand when you say ``is the a was to get the sales record for a product``.

Comment: I created a brand module in the product, for example `apple` .  to add the second item in the table `product ` I need to loop through the lines with the domain `apple` how to get remaining items in Inventory all the time of this sale

Comment: do I need to create a new filed and save it or is that recored in odoo

Comment: In which table you add the second item?

Comment: in an excel file that will be created in `test_func`

Comment: So you need to get the product available quantity (`Inventory Units`)

Comment: You can call the `_product_available` method on the product record, and it should return a dict of the product quantities ``{"qty_available": , "virtual_available": , "incoming_qty": , "outgoing_qty": ,} ``

Comment: Thank Q, I wil try it.